# Measurability of the Cartesian sum of measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove the following:

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ be arbitrary Lebesgue measurable subsets. Then, for $f\in L^1(X)$ and $g\in L^1(Y)$, the Cartesian sum of $f$ and $g$, $f\oplus g\colon X\times Y\to\mathbb{R}$, $(x,y)\mapsto f(x)+g(y)$, is an element of $L^1(X\times Y)$.

While the integrability of $f\oplus g$ is trivial to see, I'm really confused about its measurability...

The mapping $(r,s)\mapsto r+s$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and thus $(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable. If we show the $(\mathcal{B}(X)\otimes\mathcal{B}(Y))$-$(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurability of the mapping $(f\times g)(x,y):=(f(x),g(x))$, we are done. For this purpose, we choose some element $B$ of the generator of $(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, i.e., $B\in\{\pi_i^{-1}(A)\colon A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),~i=1,2\}$, where $\pi_i$ is the projection from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ onto the $i$-th compnent. W.l.o.g. we assume that $B\in\{\pi_1^{-1}(A)\colon A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$. Then, $B=A\times\mathbb{R}$, with some $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, and we calculate $$(f\times g)^{-1}(B)=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y\colon (f(x),g(y))\in A\times\mathbb{R}\}=f^{-1}(A)\times Y=\pi_X^{-1}(f^{-1}(A))$$ and since $f$ is $\mathcal{B}(X)$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable, this is some element of the generator of $\mathcal{B}(X)\otimes\mathcal{B}(Y)$ and thus an element of the latter.

Is this proof correct? If so, is there a simpler, if not trivial, argument? Is there some way to use the property $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: It seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Maybe you could write it a slightly lighter way. For instance:

If we show the $(\mathcal{B}(X)\otimes\mathcal{B}(Y))$-$(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurability of the mapping $(f\times g)(x,y):=(f(x),g(x))$, we are done. For this purpose, we choose some element $A\times B$ of the generator of $(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, i.e. a rectangle $A\times B$ where $A, B  \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Then

$$(f\times g)^{-1}(A \times B)=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y\colon (f(x),g(y))\in A\times B \}=f^{-1}(A)\times g^{-1}(B)$$ and since $f$ is $\mathcal{B}(X)$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable and $g$ is $\mathcal{B}(Y)$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable, we have that $f^{-1}(A)\times g^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{B}(X)\otimes\mathcal{B}(Y)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you!